# Is ftruncate considered a "write operation" for the purposes of O_SYNC?

Tags: linux, file-io, posix, durability

When writing to a file opened with `O_SYNC`, the data (and metadata) is guaranteed to be written to persistent storage when the write call returns, and no explicit `fsync` call is needed.

Is the same true for `ftruncate`? Or do I still need to call `fsync` after `ftruncate` even with `O_SYNC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all filesystems are capable of dealing with holes. There will be some filesystems that actually have to physically write 0's when you call `ftruncate()`.

So logically, `ftruncate()` be treated like a `write()` and be subject to `O_SYNC`.

The [POSIX definition of O_SYNC](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) says:

> Write I/O operations on the file descriptor shall complete as defined by synchronized I/O file integrity completion.

And the [POSIX definition for "synchronized I/O file integrity completion"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html):

> Identical to a synchronized I/O data integrity completion with the addition that all file attributes relative to the I/O operation [...] are successfully transferred prior to returning to the calling process.

And the definition for "Synchronized I/O Data Integrity Completion":

> [...] The write is complete only when the data specified in the write request is successfully transferred and all file system information required to retrieve the data is successfully transferred.

That includes the file size.
But notably it only applies to "writes" (and "reads").

However, neither POSIX nor the Linux man pages define what a "write" or "write I/O" is, and in particular, whether `ftruncate()` counts as one.

So if you want to get lawyery about it, it is not strictly guaranteed anywhere, although I think it's a bug in the specification.

In practice, though, I doubt any file system that implements `O_SYNC` and `ftruncate()` would require you to call `fsync()` after `ftruncate()` of a file opened with `O_SYNC`.